# ValueListenableBuilder builder method not called after updating Notifier value of List (Solved)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, state-management

While updating  ValueNotifier<List> notifier, the UI is not getting updated while changing a particular Index.
`notifier.value[index] = false;`

In that case, I have came to a solution. We can create a temporary List and empty the notifier value first and then we can insert the new value here in the following manner.

```
List<bool> temp=notifier.value;
temp[index]=false;
notifier.value=[];
notifier.value=temp;
```

This worked for me. If anyone can find better and simple code, kindly reply for this

Comment: this is because of that `if`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/796c8ef79279f9c774545b3771238c3098dbefab/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L526 - if you don't like that behaviour simply create your own `MySuperBetterValueNotifier` without that `if`

Answer (score 0):

`ValueNotifier` checks for updates by comparing the new value and the old value using the == operator.  i.e. It will only get notified with immutable data types.

[ValueNotifier's limitations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html#limitations)

`List` in dart is mutable since you can add, remove, and modify elements in a list after it has been created.  Modifying a list will not trigger the `ValueNotifier` to update.  If you modify the list by doing `notifier.value[index] = false;`, the old list and the new list are considered the same by the `ValueNotifier` and thus it will not trigger an update.

If you are using mutable data type with `ValueNotifier` , you should create a new instance and assign it to update the notifier.

```dart
final numbersNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<int>>([0, 1, 2]);

// Instead of doing
numbersNotifier.value = numbersNotifier.value..add(3);

// You should create a new instance and assign it
numbersNotifier.value = [...numbersNotifier.value, 3];
```

You may also check out some packages that provide immutable collection data type
such as [fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections).

Comment: For add method it works fine, what about updation?

Comment: Just like what you did, you could create a temporary list, update the list, and assign it to the `ValueNotifier`.

You could also use [collection if and collection for](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators) to create a new list.